# JAVA/PDF: add table rows dynamicly from .doc template to .pdf output

Tags: java, pdf, open-source, richtextbox, doc

My privious question actually just showed one of the solutions I am trying to do.The real situation is as following:

`/**(1)Our clients(A) will offer us(B) templates in .doc format
 *(2)We should fill all of the empty tables with data rows accroding to the table-head in  templates.
 *(3)The output of these documents shoulded be delivered in .pdf format to users(C) for the seek of avoiding being changed.
 *(4)PS-->part of the final PDF contents are come from rich-text-editor stored in database through browers.So the pdf is make up with two main parts totally 
**/`

(5)PPS-->It has to **support Chinese**

My idea is that to handle the .doc templates and rich-text seperately bacause I haven't found a "silver bullet" as far.And I will combine the two .pdf parts together later.

(1)**the rich-text part :** I will use flying-saucer or pef-box to generate a temp .pdf  file from html. documents

(2)**the .doc template part :** that's my trying here.

```
1,I tried FOP and other xstl library, but it can't work with .doc well.
2,I can not use itext because the format of the .doc is complex and strict, it would kill me if I make a .pdf looking like the same as the .doc tempates with code.
3,I have worked with flying-saucer in the folowing steps:
      1).doc transformed to .html documents
      2)edit the .html documents with free-marker language to generte .flt templates
      3)fill table rows in .flt with dynamic data fetched from database generate middle xhtml stream
      4)generate .pdf file from xhtml stream with flying-saucer
```

As you can see, my solution is really so awkward.It would not be a good solution to handle with 100+ templates.

**Here is my question:**
(1)Is there a "silver bullet" can handle .doc(should be dynamiclly added table row datas) and rich-text(html/xhtml) to my .pdf file?

(2)If there is not(I really can not find one.).How should I work out it?And How should I deal with the .doc templates?

(3)@MihaiC give me a solution, but my boss does not buy it cause he want me to try an open-source solution.So, if use the oracle publisher,can I use it freely and with full function now and i futrue?

======================privious qustion edited on Dec 3' 2014============================

I have a pdf tampalte file that has **a table only with a table-head**. Now I need to **add table rows contents** accroding to data fetched from my database.
I have searched a lot in SO, but I can't find a solution to this problem.
Does anyone know if there is a java library can help me do this?

PS->

I **dont't want to create a new table** for the pdf file but add rows following the table head.

The reason why I can't create a pdf from scratch is that the format of the output pdf file is so strict that it is too complex to create it by code.So I need to just use the pdf template file to maintain it's format and layout

Comment: you can use the libraries from oracle bi publisher desktop. they can generate pdf file based on .rtf template

Comment: "Tables" in finished PDFs usually only visually appear to us as tables, inside the PDF itself they are merely a collection of lines or rectangles and text pieces; so usually you cannot easily add new rows to existing tables. Are your templates different?

Comment: my pdf files are not template.Just as the @MihaiC said, I need to generate pdf file from a template file. Actually, I think I have not clearified my question. My clients will offer their templates in .doc format. And I have to fill all empty tables with data fetched from database. And then I have to output the final documents with .pdf format to avoided be changed by others.The develop environment is java and linux.

Comment: @cosmoseeker *my pdf files are not template* - ah, thanx for clarifying. Due to your original "I have a pdf tampalte file" I thought they were. *My clients will offer their templates in .doc format* - have you looked at Office automation (MS or OpenOffice)? That might work.

Comment: First, MS can not be used bacause it is a web project run in linux environment and should be developed with java.Second, you mentioned Open Office, actually I did lokked at it. But I think it is a software, not a develop library.I have read the introduction in wikipedia and officail website.I don't think it can be used as a library in my eclipse.Did I omitted something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understood your problem, I think what you need is a way of generating a `pdf` starting from a `template` file which can be changed over time, and data from the database.

For this, you can use the libraries from [Oracle Bi Publisher Desktop](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-publisher/downloads/index.html). Their location is usually

`C:\Program Files\Oracle\BI Publisher\BI Publisher Desktop\TemplateViewer\lib`

The ones you need are (names might have changed since newer versions, but more or less are the same, if in doubt add all the ones located there in your project)

```
i18nAPI_v3
versioninfo
xdocore
xmlparserv2-904
```

You can read tutorials about building `RTF` templates such as [Creating RTF Templates](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_rtf_tmpl.htm#BIPRD2366). There is a plethora of examples available online.

You need to convert data from your database into xml format, since the libraries use the tags to identify rows and data.

First you will need to define such a method for the query results returned by the database.

You could use [JAXB](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html#jaxb)

```
public byte[] getXMLData() { ... }
```

The below method will generate a report based on the `xml` generated from the `getXMLData()` method, and a `templateFile`, having the `outFileType` output file type.

```
public byte[] getReport(String templateFile, String outFileType) {
    byte[] dataBytes = null;
    try {
        //Process RTF template to convert to XSL-FO format
        RTFProcessor rtfp = new RTFProcessor(templateFile);
        ByteArrayOutputStream xslOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        rtfp.setOutput(xslOutStream);
        rtfp.process();

        ByteArrayInputStream xslInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xslOutStream.toByteArray());

        FOProcessor processor = new FOProcessor();
        ByteArrayInputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(getXMLData());
        processor.setData(dataStream);
        processor.setTemplate(xslInStream);

        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        processor.setOutput(pdfOutStream);
        byte outFileTypeByte = FOProcessor.FORMAT_PDF;
        if ("HTML".equalsIgnoreCase(outFileType)) {
            outFileTypeByte = FOProcessor.FORMAT_HTML;
        } else if ("RTF".equalsIgnoreCase(outFileType)) {
            outFileTypeByte = FOProcessor.FORMAT_RTF;
        }
        processor.setOutputFormat(outFileTypeByte);
        processor.generate();

        dataBytes = pdfOutStream.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IOException when generating pdf " + e);

    } catch (XDOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("XDOException when generating pdf " + e);

    }
    return dataBytes;
}
```

Generate the `pdf` report by calling something like:

```
public byte[] getReport() {
   String templatePath ="<pathToTemplate>/Template.rtf";
   return getReport(templatePath, "pdf");
}
```

Comment: The OP has a **PDF** template, not a **RTF** one.

Comment: @mkl yes, this is a workaround so he can use a rtf template in which he can add data dynamically. i don't know of any way to use a pdf template since it's contents are all lines and rectangles, so i think he needs to create code with which he can insert more lines and rectangles inside the template based on the data from the db. with my proposed workaround he can write his own rtf template and reuse it anytime. i will delete the answer if it won't help, assumed op is looking for a way to handle templates, regardless of it's type. this is a good and easy way to do it.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I haven't asked a proper question.The actual situation would like this. Our clients will offer us **templates with .doc format**.(1)first, we should fill empty tables with table-head already in those templates.(2)second,We should offer final document as .pdf foramt instead of .doc to avoid being changed by others who download these final files.**Problem**:As I worked in **linux and java** environment, I can not use openxml or something like that.I searched a lot and tried a lot,but not a solution can solve all the problem perfectly

Comment: @cosmoseeker my solution should provide the desired functionality. a .doc template can be saved as .rtf . try it out! you don't need to install bi publisher desktop on linux. Install it on your local machine and just copy the libs i wrote about into your project. The only "real" challenge here is getting data from the database into xml format so you can pass it to the libraries. This shouldn't be hard to do

Comment: @cosmoseeker edited my answer to include library for xml generation of objects (JAXB http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html#jaxb)

Comment: I just showed the solution to my teacher. He asked me trying to find an open-source solution.Maybe he is worried about that the Oracle stuff would need fees in future.Thanks a lot any way and I will try this.

Comment: those oracle libs shouldn't need fees in the future, they have been around for many years. usually oracle offers a lot of their software for free and you only pay for support. i think it's fine to use it. I use this solution to generate bank reports in various banking applications (where the templates can change often). I wish you luck with your project, and if you have any more questions about this implementation let me know.

Comment: @MihaiC Sorry for my criticism... you seem to have understood the OP better already in his original question.